# Simple overloading of operator= not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I'm in the process of modifying my [`integer`](http://calccrypto.wikidot.com/programming%3ainteger) class (that's not my most updated copy, but it works with `-std=c++0x`). I came across a *slight* problem: a simple operator overloading refuses to work no matter what I do. this code:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

class integer{
    private:
        std::deque <uint8_t> value;

    public:
        integer(){}

        integer operator=(int rhs){
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
        integer a = 132;        
        return 0;
}
```

gives me: `error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘integer’ requested`, but isn't that the whole point of overloading `operator=`? I have changed the `int` part to `template <typename T>` but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Furthermore, the assignment operator shouldn’t return by value.

Comment: You're missing capital letters in your post.

Comment: If you are trying to cast an int to an integer (what I assume you are doing), you might want to implement a copy constructor that takes an int instead of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You're not using the `=` operator at all there; even though the `=` symbol is present, initialisation is done only with constructors. Some people prefer construction-type initialisation for clarity for that reason:

```
T a = 1;    // ctor
T b(2);     // ctor
T c; c = 3; // ctor then op=
```

So, you need a constructor that can take `int`. Don't forget to mark it `explicit`.

Additionally, by the way, an assignment operator should return a reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
integer a = 132;
```

Is initialization. It calls the conversion constructor, not `operator =`.

```
integer a;
a = 132;
```

should work, but better define the constructor:

```
integer(int rhs){}
```

Also note that `operator =` should return by reference.